# How to get Exact products by query in Magento 2

Tags: database, magento-2.1, catalogsearch, query

When we search the products in search bar Magento 2 will search and display the **Relevance** products followed by `http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=sample+product`.

I can see the method where Magento 2 rendering these products.

**Module_Search/Model/ResourceModel/Query/Collection.php**

```
/**
     * Set search query text to filter
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setQueryFilter($query)
    {
        $this->getSelect()->reset(
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM
        )->distinct(
            true
        )->from(
            ['main_table' => $this->getTable('search_query')]
        )->where(
            'num_results > 0 AND display_in_terms = 1 AND query_text LIKE ?',
            $this->_resourceHelper->addLikeEscape($query, ['position' => 'start'])
        )->order(
            'popularity ' . \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC
        );
        if ($this->getStoreId()) {
            $this->getSelect()->where('store_id = ?', (int)$this->getStoreId());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Now I want to change this query to exact product search like below `Query`.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE "% Sample Product %";
```

How can I change Magento 2 `setQueryFilter($query)` Query condition?

Any help